# Auto format #1234 string in Microsoft Teams channel

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is it possible to add some code or something else to make it possible that whenever I type a hashtag followed by a number that this will be replaced by a url?

My requirement is whenever some developer mention a ticket number like `#1234` in his chat post into a channel I want to make this clickable and directly opens a url like `myticketsystem.com?id=1234`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to implement an auto-linking similar to how GitHub handles things like `Fixes issue #xxxx`? It isn't possible to implement this in Teams today, it isn't possible to inject your own logic into the composition rendering pipeline.

What you could do however is build a [Compose Extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/composeextensions). This wouldn't replicate the GitHub experience but it would certainty make it easier to insert links to tickets into the compose editor. It could also be a more powerful tool, allowing users to search the ticketing system rather than having to know the number before writing the post.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I will take a look at your link. And yes, this was exactly what I wanted, enter a #Number and parse it to a link. When I push data from using a webhook url I already can do this using markdown syntax formatting the link.

Comment: I love the concept, but it would be tricky to implement without risking performance issues (imagine someone installing 25 add-ins that all processed each post). It may however be possible to do this externally using Microsoft Graph once those APIs get fleshed out a little more (currently you wouldn't be able to edit the post to add the URI).